# find overlapping addresses in the table

Tags: sql

i have an addresses table say :

```
address id person_id start_date stop_date address 
1          123       01-JAN-15  01-JUN-15 india
2          123       01-MAY-15  null      Russia
3          321       01-JAN-15  01-JUN-15 us
4          321       01-MAY-15  null      india
```

I want to find all records(address ids ) which has overlapping dates for the same person_id .in this eg address_id 1 and 4. As may lies between jan and jun

Comment: What database are you using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why 1 and 4? They're not for the same person_id...?

Comment: but each entry has to be tracked by unique address id even if it is for same person

Comment: @KaranBhandari Yes, but you say *overlapping dates for the same person_id* and your example is two rows that indeed overlap but don't have the same person_id.

Comment: for address_id 1 and 2 person_id is 123 (same) and for address_id 3 and 4 person id is 321. and ans would be address_id 2 and 4,,my bad (

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
select address_id 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT null 
             FROM table1 t2 
             WHERE t1.person_id=t2.person_id 
             AND t1.start_date BETWEEN t2.start_date AND t2.end_date)
```